# I want to build a OSX app that applies some simple dsp to all audio. Where do I get started?

Tags: cocoa, macos, signal-processing, core-audio

I want to build a little utility app that sits in the OSX tool bar and allows a user to apply a little dsp (equalization, etc.) to whatever audio is playing.

E.g., A user could adjust the equalization of the overall sound, regardless of what app the audio is playing in.

What Libraries, APIs, will allow me to tap into the audio stream?

This is my first time to program for OSX so any advice, help with gotchas, on this topic would be appreciated!

Comment: If you just want to get the job done rather than programming it, `Audio Hijack Pro` from Rogue Amoeba does this and much more.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Audio Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Units).

AU Lab can be configured as a [system-wide equalizer](http://www.dctrwatson.com/2011/06/os-x-system-equalizer/), when combined with [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/).